# Effect sibling element on hover using sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two elements in a div. One of them is hidden and I want to show it when someone hover on the visible one. Through normal `CSS` I have done this, but I am unable to do this through `SASS`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class"main">
<a href="#"> Link to my account </a>
<p> john </p>
</div>
```

I have tried it but it doesn't work for me.

```
.main {
    position: relative;

    a {
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: gray;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    a:hover p {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

So how to make the `p` tag visible when someone hover on the `a` tag using SASS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a `SASS` problem, you just have to use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```
a:hover + p {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: you can also use :-a:hover >p {
   visibility: visible;
}

Comment: No @ArpitJain.  `>` is a immediate child selector not for sibling !

Comment: yes, It's working now. Thanks

Comment: @ArpitJain `>` using for the first child.

Answer (score 1):

The adjacent sibling selector selects all elements that are the adjacent siblings of a specified element.The following change should help you.

```
.main {
    position: relative;

    a {
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: gray;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    a:hover + p {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: Yes, Amazing it's working. Thanks for a quick response.